# Custom Submit button

Tags: cakephp, forms, button, submit

How can I create submit button, and define custom title on it, together with custom class style?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also remember, you can always do it **old school**

I prefer to use `$this->Form->end( );` without arguments and build my own submit buttons and markup. It's easy

```
<div class="buttons clearfix">
    <button type="submit" class="positive">
        <span class="icon-wrapper"><img src="path/to/tickmark.png" alt="" title="" /></span>
        Save Item
    </button>
</div>
```

I would also tell you to experiment with the `$this->Form->input('Model.field', 'options' => array( array('type' => 'button')));` - particularly the before, between, after, and class options. You can use the helper to create `<input type="button" />` elements with a good amount of flexibility.

Answer (score 32):

You could use either [`submit()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1431/submit) or [`button()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1415/button) methods of the Form helper instead of the `end()` method. For example:

```
echo $this->Form->submit(
    'Send', 
    array('class' => 'custom-class', 'title' => 'Custom Title')
);
```

Don't forget to close the form. You can do it by calling the `end()` method without any arguments.

```
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create costum submit by this code

```
echo $this->Form->submit(
    'Submit', 
    array('div' => false,'class' => 'urclass', 'title' => 'Title')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

This is enough:

```
echo $this->Form->submit("Custom message");
```

Also as @Mike suggest close the form with

```
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can combine both with:

```
echo $this->Form->end("Custom Message");
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom button using an image in my under app/webroot/img that uses inline style for specifying size and changing the position to center

```
$options=array('type'=>'Make secure payment', 'type'=>'image', 'style'=>'width:200px; height:80px; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;');
echo $this->Form->submit('/img/axiaepaysecurebuttongray_med.png', $options);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 2.x, you can use

```
$options = array(
    'label' => 'Update',
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'glass-pill',
    )
);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
```