# Big red cancel button on a cakephp form

Tags: cakephp

There is a form with normal:

```
$this->Form->create('Users');
$this->Form->input('name');
```

...
that ends in

```
$this->Form->end('Submit');
```

I want to add a cancel button next to it.

```
$this->Html->link('Cancel', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'))
```

This produces a link but I want a button.

Is there a Cake PHP way of getting this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no pure Cake way to create such a button that I know of. I think it's easiest to use the button() method of the Form helper, adding a click event to the Cancel button and just end the form without any arguments in the end() method.

```
$this->Form->create('Users');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->button('Submit');
echo $this->Form->button('Cancel', array(
   'type' => 'button',
   'onclick' => 'location.href=\'/users\''
));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button like this:

> $this->Form->input("", array("type"=>"button", "name" => "Cancel"));

You can add any html button attribute in the array that's in 2nd param of input.

or

> $this->Form->button(
>       'Click me', 
>       array()
>       )
>   );

For that you need to remove `$this->Form->end('Submit');` and instead of this use this:

```
$this->Form->submit('Submit'); //the submit button
// put the button code i mentioned above
$this->Form->end(); // and then for closing form tag
```

[See This link for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182110/custom-submit-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of bootstrap button classes "btn btn-danger" for this purpose.

```
echo $this->Form->button('Cancel', array(
   'type' => 'button',
   'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
   'onclick' => 'location.href=\'/users\''
));
```